# How to copy the content of one word document into another word document?

Tags: c#

I have a word document with some Text and Images. I want to copy the content of the word document into another word document using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: copy the file to a new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should do the trick.
This will copy all contents from first document to second document. Make sure both documents exists.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument firstDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"E:\firstDocument.docx", false))
using (WordprocessingDocument secondDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"E:\secondDocument.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    foreach (var part in firstDocument.Parts)
    {
        secondDocument.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer because it's using OpenXML which is recommended for unattended server side operations.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code . This may help you .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var sourceDoc =    app.Documents.Open(@"D:\test.docx");

            sourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            sourceDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

            var newDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            newDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
            newDocument.SaveAs(@"D:\test1.docx");

            sourceDoc.Close(false);
            newDocument.Close();

            app.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sourceDoc);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newDocument);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below function will show you how to open - close and copy from word doc.

```
using MsWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
private static void MsWordCopy()
    {
        var wordApp = new MsWord.Application();
        MsWord.Document documentFrom = null, documentTo = null;

        try
        {
            var fileNameFrom = @"C:\MyDocFile.docx";               

            wordApp.Visible = true;

            documentFrom = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileNameFrom, Type.Missing, true);
            MsWord.Range oRange = documentFrom.Content;
            oRange.Copy();

            var fileNameTo = @"C:\MyDocFile-Copy.docx";
            documentTo = wordApp.Documents.Add();
            documentTo.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType: MsWord.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
            documentTo.SaveAs(fileNameTo);              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (documentFrom != null)
                documentFrom.Close(false);

            if (documentTo != null)
                documentTo.Close();

            if (wordApp != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);

            wordApp = null;
            documentFrom = null;
            documentTo = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
```