# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem is blank on some systems

Tags: .net, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to automate a report for my manager and using the below code to generate the email body.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = GenerateEmailBody("abc","xyz","Weekly Summary - Week  " + WeekNumber + " " + DateTime.Now.Year);
```

I am using the Interop libraries. The GenerateBody is doing nothing special except generating the To,Subject, HTML body and returning the MailItem object back.

Now, the funny thing is that the email window opened on my system shows the right content and everything, where as on my Managers system the Body of the outlook window is blank!

Typical bad luck scenario,

To troubleshoot I already checked the default email format as html and default fonts availability on both the systems.

Any suggestions ? Here's the body of my GenerateEmailBody function

[image]

Comment: Post the code, not images of the code. Images can't be copied or compiled

Comment: As for why the code is failing, it looks like you're *pasting* whatever is in the clipboard instead of adding anything to the body. If the clipboard is empty, the body will be empty. The `wordDocumentEditor` is actually a Word Document. Use Word's API to create the text instead of copy/pasting. Check [How to: Programmatically insert text into Word documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-insert-text-into-word-documents?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Actually yes, 
I am copying the content of 1 of my Word windows to an outlook email,
wordDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
wordDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

Strangely, this does work on my system and not on another

Comment: Check [How to copy the content of one word document into another word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382093/how-to-copy-the-content-of-one-word-document-into-another-word-document). You already have access to the actual document since you use Interop, you don't need to go through the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calling the `Display` method after all modifications.

Note, Outlook may not propagate changes made through the OOM immediately, or otherwise, changes made in the UI may not be accessible via OOM immediately until you switch to another field or just save the changes. This is a known issue when dealing with OOM.

You may try to call the `Save` to get your changes propagated to the Outlook UI.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the code was correct, nothing wrong with the code,but Thank you all for your Answers.

Although, coming to the solution,

> The machine where the email content wasnt available had a default
>   signature set for new email messages, and was an HTML signature. So when we disabled the Email signature, the email content was visible

Seriously very strange behavior.

I suspect something to do with this line being called

```
oMailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
```